# Are there any annuals I can sow this late in the year (end of June)?

Tags: flowers, seeds, sowing

Are there any flowering annuals I can still sow in the second half of June? I've just transplanted out some marigolds that I threw into seed compost in the Spring and basically neglected in a corner of the greenhouse ever since. They were getting a bit sad in their seed tray. But after two days out in a comfy bed they're looking brilliant.

I had forgotten how easy they are to grow.

Are there any flowers/bedding plants I can sow at this stage and repeat this trick for some late summer colour in a few weeks time?

I am in the south of the UK.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've had good luck planting cosmos late. According to what I see for numbers, you can expect [bloom 55-90 days after germination](http://www.google.com/search?q=cosmos+bloom+%22days+after+germination%22).

[image: Late cosmos in bloom]

Comment: i bought some seeds today. let's see what happens

Comment: @Tea Drinker: good luck, let me know how it works out 55-90 days from today...

Comment: they came out just fine!

Comment: @TeaDrinker: Glad it worked out, thanks for the update!

Answer (score 7):

Calendula, sunflowers (they'll be short), dill & nasturtiums. Not sure if you'll get flowers in a few weeks, maybe 5-7 weeks depedning on your growing zone. Oh, and all those flowers are edible.